# How to calculate byte/index ranges for mpeg-dash MPD file?

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, mpeg-dash, ffprobe

I basically know how an .mpd file would have to be structured to support streaming from separate .mp4 (or webm) files.

However, I would like to implement the "static" (aka "on-demand") method, thus only having one file per quality that I want to offer in the stream.

In all samples, this is done by supplying the **indexRange & range** values within a Representation like this:

```
<Representation bandwidth="2073921" codecs="avc1.4d401f" height="720" id="2" mimeType="video/mp4" width="1280">
        <BaseURL>car-20120827-88.mp4</BaseURL>
        <SegmentBase indexRange="708-1183">
          <Initialization range="0-707" />
        </SegmentBase>
</Representation>
```

What I could not find out anywhere is how one would calculate the indexRange/range values here, using only ffmpeg (or ffprobe).
What **exactly** would one have to do to get those numbers right for arbitrary (yet supported, of course) video files to create the .mpd file for them?

Or am I trying to figure out something in vain here and those values are just arbitrary?

Comment: Might this be useful? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14751134/how-to-create-a-mpd-file-of-mpeg-dash-to-play-a-webm-video

Comment: Unfortunately not, since none of the links describes how to get those values exactly, only what those values are. GPAC/MP4Box is mentioned often, but I would prefer a solution without that tool.

Comment: Of course, if mp4box is the only thing capable of producing useful indexRange number, I will have to, but I do hope there is another way.

Comment: You will need to use or write a tool like mp4box. ffmpeg will not do it without rewriting the file. The numbers are not arbitrary. They are specific start points of each fragment

Comment: I would be fine with ffmpeg rewriting the file, as I use the ffmpeg API on the C/C++ level to create the video in the first place, so I have full control there.